# how can I disable a push button after it was clicked once?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

I'v created a GUI with a button called "start".

After it was clicked once, I need this button to be disabled.

the button definition:

```py
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.start, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.constant)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to connect the clicked signal to invoke the setDisabled method, and to do it in a few lines you can use functools.partial.

```py
from functools import partial

# ...

wrapper = partial(self.start.setDisabled, True)
self.start.clicked.connect(wrapper)
```